# How to verify a certificate against an issuing chain in Go?

Tags: go, certificate, x509, pki

I'd like to verify a PEM certificate against an issuing chain which is also a `.pem` file with several certificates separated by newline characters as shown in this gist, https://gist.github.com/kurtpeek/8bf3282e344c781a20c5deadac75059f. I've tried this with `Certpool.AppendCertsFromPEM` as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/pem"
    "io/ioutil"

    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func main() {
    caCertPEM, err := ioutil.ReadFile("issuing_chain.pem")
    if err != nil {
        logrus.WithError(err).Fatal("read CA PEM file")
    }

    certPEM, err := ioutil.ReadFile("3007e750-e769-440b-9075-41dc2b5b1787.pem")
    if err != nil {
        logrus.WithError(err).Fatal("read cert PEM file")
    }

    block, rest := pem.Decode(certPEM)
    if block == nil {
        logrus.WithField("rest", rest).Fatal("Decode CA PEM")
    }

    cert, err := x509.ParseCertificate(block.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        logrus.WithError(err).Fatal("parse certificate")
    }

    roots := x509.NewCertPool()
    roots.AppendCertsFromPEM(caCertPEM)

    chain, err := cert.Verify(x509.VerifyOptions{Roots: roots})
    if err != nil {
        logrus.WithError(err).Fatal("failed to verify cert")
    }

    logrus.Infof("issuing chain: %+v", chain)
}
```

However, if I run this I get the following error:

```
FATA[0000] failed to verify cert                         error="x509: certificate specifies an incompatible key usage"
exit status 1
```

I believe this error is returned on line 790 of https://golang.org/src/crypto/x509/verify.go:

```
if len(chains) == 0 {
    return nil, CertificateInvalidError{c, IncompatibleUsage, ""}
}
```

In other words, the `Verify()` method is unable to build any `chains` from the options provided. I've tried splitting out the intermediates (the top two in the `issuing_chain.pem` shown in the gist) into a separate PEM file and adding those as `Intermediates` to the `x509.VerifyOptions`, but I still get the same error.

What is the correct way to verify a certificate against an issuing chain in Go?

Comment: Maybe some of those certificates are intermediate certificates. The validation options want roots and intermediates separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your leaf certificate is for client authentication only.

```
$ openssl x509 -noout -text -in leaf.pem  | grep -A1 'Key Usage'
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Client Authentication
```

If this is intentional, you must specify the KeyUsages option because ["an empty list means ExtKeyUsageServerAuth"](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#VerifyOptions.KeyUsages). You also have to go back to your version of the code that provides the intermediate certs separately:

```
chain, err := cert.Verify(x509.VerifyOptions{
    Roots:         roots,
    Intermediates: inters,
    KeyUsages:     []x509.ExtKeyUsage{x509.ExtKeyUsageClientAuth},
})
```

Try it on the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/1BNLthzu5Tz. Note that the playground requires the CurrentTime option to verify correctly. Remove this when copying elsewhere!